# How to demonstrate sigma(i/2^i)<=2 (i=1 to n)

Tags: series

How to demonstrate following Unequal:

```
sigma(i/2^i)<=2 (i=1 to n)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a logical proof, not programming. math.SE might be open to this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we look at the **series** then it looks like:
We consider n = infinity for maximum value of sum.
`S = 1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 + 4/16 + 5/32 +.... + 0` **- (1)**
Clearly, 
`S/2 = 1/4 + 2/8 + 3/16 + 4/32 + ---- + 0` **- (2)**

Subtracting (2) from (1) we get:
`S/2 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 +... + 0`

In this `a = 1/2` and `r = 1/2` so sum of this infinite gp is `a/(1-r) = 1/2/(1-1/2) = 1`

So maximum value of S/2 is 1
then **maximum value of S is 2** or `S <= 2`

Comment: The **series** is:
1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 +...+n/(2^n)
So how we can consider a constant like _a_?

Comment: Yup consider case when n = infinity value will be maximum

Comment: Made certain changes @AliABidgoli

Comment: 1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 +... is aproximatly 2 so its strictly greater that 1.

Comment: Saw the correct series just now, made some changes @AliABidgoli Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The sum of a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ... is given by a / (1 - r). If only a finite number of terms are present, there is a non-negative remainder, that is, the sum will be [ a / (1 - r) ] - R.  Plugging in the values of a and r, i get 2 - R.  It seems that this is consistently <= 2.  Q.E.D.