# complexity of heap data structure

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, binary-tree, big-o, heap

I'm trying to count running time of build heap in heap sort algorithm

```
BUILD-HEAP(A) 
heapsize := size(A); 
  for i := floor(heapsize/2) downto 1 
    do HEAPIFY(A, i); 
  end for 
END
```

The basic idea behind why the time is linear is due to the fact that the time complexity of heapify depends on where it is within the heap. It takes O(1) time when the node is a leaf node (which makes up at least half of the nodes) and O(logn) time when it’s at the root.

The O(n) time can be proven by solving the following:

[image] [image by HostMath](https://www.HostMath.com/Show.aspx?Code=%5Csum_%7Bh%3D0%7D%5E%20%7B%5Clfloor%20lg%20n%20%5Crfloor%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2%5E%7Bh%2B1%7D%7DO(h)%3DO(n%5Csum_%7Bh%3D0%7D%5E%20%7Blg%20n%7D%5Cfrac%7Bh%7D%7B2%5E%7Bh%7D%7D))

what I understand here O(h) means worst case for heapify for each node, so height=ln n if the node is in the root for example to heapify node 2,1,3 it takes ln_2 3 =1.5 the height of root node 2 is 1, so the call to HEAPIFY is ln_2 n=height = O(h)

```
BUILD-HEAP(A) 
heapsize := size(A); 
  for i := floor(heapsize/2) downto 1 
    do HEAPIFY(A, i); 
  end for 
END 




 suppose this is the tree

       4    .. height2
      / \ 
    2   6  .. height 1
    /\   /\  
  1 3 5 7  .. height 0
```

A quick look over the above algorithm suggests that the running time is O(nlg(n)), since each call to Heapify costs O(lg(n)) and Build-Heap makes O(n) such calls.
This upper bound, though correct, is not asymptotically tight.
 the Time complexity for Building a Binary Heap is O(n).

im trying to understand, the heapsize/2 means for loop only call HEAPIFY heapsize/2 times. in tree above, heapsize=7, 7/2= 3 so root will be {1,2,6} so n/2

and every call to HEAPIFY will call HEAPIFY again until reach the last leaf of every root,
for example 2 will call heapify 1 times, 6 will call heapify  1 times, and 1 will call heapify  2 times. so it is the height of the tree which is ln n. am i right?

then the compelxity will be O(n/2 * ln n) = O(n ln n)

which one is right? O(n ln n) or O(n)?

and how can i get O(n)?

im reading this as reference , please correct me if im wrong thanks! 
https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/data-structures/binary-heap/build-heap-proof/
this is the reference i used, and also i read about this in CLRS book

https://www.hostmath.com/Show.aspx?Code=ln_2%203

Comment: your question is illegible, especially where you used '$'.

Comment: Unfortunately Latex formulas are not rendered (duh, right).  See StackOverflow meta question [LaTeX on Stack Overflow: any way to include a formula?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309307/latex-on-stack-overflow-any-way-to-include-a-formula).  You might want to migrate your question to comp-sci s.o., http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Richard thankyou for the edit! im trying to use chart.googleapis in link you suggested but there is no picture shown just the link? and also i try to put image, but my reputation is under 10 so i cant add image. i also try 
https://www.HostMath.com/Show.aspx?Code=ln_2%203 to put this link but no image shown?

Comment: I haven't tried the google apis, Try https://www.hostmath.com for your online Latex renders.  Rep is close, so guess you can revisit soon later with image edits, or repost on comp sci, or mock up the formula in as best in code formatted text (stuff inside back ticks `code format`)

Comment: @Richard thankyou,for hostmath did you copy the external URL and paste the URL link? i tried but only the URL showed up,   no image?  for example https://www.hostmath.com/Show.aspx?Code=ln_2%203

Comment: I use Windows 10, and Snipping Tool to grab rectangular snip of formula rendering from hostmath web page.  Copy (image) and paste into StackOverflow editor will auto upload and insert markup to view the upload inline (when you click accept)

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/49774237/56778, which explains why the maximum number of comparisons in building a heap is `2N - 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity is O(n) here is why. Let's assume that the tree has **n** nodes. Since a heap is a nearly complete binary tree (according to CLRS), the second half of nodes are all leaves; so, there is no need to heapify them. Now for the remaining half. We start from node at position n/2 and go backwards. In heapifying, a node can only move downwards so, as you mentioned, it takes at most as much as the height of the node swap operations to complete the heapify for that node.

With n nodes, we have at most log n levels, where level 0 has the root and level 1 has at most 2 nodes and so on:

```
level 0:              x
.                    / \  
level 1:            x   x
.
level log n:    x x x x x x x x
```

So, we have the following:

All nodes at level **logn-1** need at most **1** swap for being heapified. (at most n/2 nodes here)

All nodes at level **logn-2** need at most **2** swaps for being heapified. (at most n/4 nodes here)

....

All nodes at level **0** need at most **logn** swaps for being heapified. (at most 1 node here, i.e, the root)

So, the sum can be written as follows:

(1 x n/2 + 2 x n/4 + 3 x n/8 + ... + log n x n/2^logn)

Let's factor out n, we get:

n x (1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 + ... + log n/2^logn)

Now the sum (1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 + ... + log n/2^logn) is always <= 2 (see [Sigma i over 2^i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983113/how-to-demonstrate-sigmai-2i-2-i-1-to-n)); therefore, the aforementioned sum we're interested in is always <= 2 x n. So, the complexity is O(n).

Comment: thankyou so much!! so it is height=log n* total nodes at height , but when you said at most n/2 nodes, in level 1 for example, there are total n=3 nodes from root, is it at most n/2=3/2 =1.5 = 2 or 1?

Comment: @devss I said at most n/2 nodes in level logn - 1. The objective is to count the amount work for each level separately. As we go up in the levels the number of nodes is divided by 2. And as we go down the number of nodes is multiplied by 2 in each level. So, level 0, 1 node. Level 1, 2 nodes. Level 3, 4 nodes.

Comment: thankyou for the explanation!! but im still confuse, when you said at most n/2 nodes in logn -1 , for example in level 3 there are 7 nodes from root, so at most 7/2 =3.5 in level log 7 -1 (?) but there are four nodes(?)

Comment: @devss I see. So, let's say there are n=7 nodes. Level 0 has 1 node, level 1 has 2 nodes, and level 2 has 4 nodes. So, logn - 1 is actually level 1 in this tree which has 2 nodes and 2 is less than or equal to (<=) 7/2. Note that I'm omitting floors since almost always they don't change the asymptotic complexity. Does that make sense?