# Max-heapify with convergent series

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, heap, heapsort

I am going through max-heapify and below was the observations

1- Observe max-heapify takes O(1) for nodes that are one level above leaves and in general O(L) times for nodes that are L level above leaves

2- n/4 nodes with level 1, n/8 nodes with level 2 so on.

The total amount of work in the for loop:

```
n/4 (1 c) + n/8 (2 c) + n/16 (3c) + ... + 1(log n c)
```

set n/4 = 2 pow k

C*2powk (1/2pow0 + 2/2pow1 + 3/2pow2 + ... + (k+1)/2powk)

series in the bracket is convergent series bounded by a constant

Algorithm is:

build max-heap (A)

```
for i=n/2 down to 1:
  do max-heapify (A,i)
```

I understand most of the thing from the lecture, but I am confused on some points

1- Why we using n/4 (1 c), why not n/2? and how we know that n/4 leads us to level 1

2- How this convergent series leads us to theta n complexity

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/49781979/56778 any help?

Comment: Yes it helped alot, Can you please help me on this (7         3          2*1 + 1*2 = 4) in your answer, heap size 7, levels 3 , how you calculate movie 2*1 + 1*2? Is it root to child then grandchild?

Comment: A heap with seven nodes has three levels. There are 4 nodes at the root level that never move. On the level above the leaf level there are two nodes that can potentially move one level down (2*1). There is one node at the root that can potentially move two levels down (1*2).

Answer (score 0):

1: Consider some (complete for simplicity) binary tree. It has one root, two nodes below the root, 4 below them and so on. Hence the number of nodes in a binary tree of height h is

`1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(h-1) = 2^h - 1`

Since this is the number of nodes n, roughly half of all nodes (n/2) are leaves. In the level above are half as many nodes as there are leaves so n/4.

2: You have a runtime of

`C * 2^k * (1 + 2/2^1 + ... + (k+1)/2^k)`

Let's call the Term in the bracket S(k) (dependent on k). We say that S(k) converges when k goes against infinity. Furthermore it is increasing, since S(k+1) is S(k) plus a positive term. Hence it has to always be lower than its limit. Would it be higher, we couldn't get down again. Therefore we can say there is a constant A (so independent of k) such that S(k) < A for all k.

Hence we can write the runtime as

`C * 2^k * (1 + 2/2^1 + ... + (k+1)/2^k) < C * 2^k * A = A * C * n/4 = O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of long explanation, I had the same difficulty to understand the heapify() before. So, I’d like to share it. Please let me know if you find some issue. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use similar technique to get the result of the sum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983113/how-to-demonstrate-sigmai-2i-2-i-1-to-n